# Remote shell (tramp) and login script

Tags: shell, tramp

When I open a file via tramp on a remote machine and then start a shell with `M-x shell` I get an infinite loop because of my .cshrc file.

I want to use a newer gcc version in CentOS so I have:

```csh
set X="`gcc -dumpversion`"
if ($x != "4.8.2") then
  scl enable devtoolset-2 tcsh
endif
```

It seems that inside emacs the `gcc -dumpversion` always gives 4.4.7 and the `scl enable` is run an infinite number of times. (The `scl enable` starts a new shell.)

When I ssh into this machine it starts fine with gcc 4.8.2.

Do I have to use any settings to get the shell in emacs tramp to work?

Comment: The code is from my login script .cshrc

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that your setup will work. You use `csh`, but Tramp supports only POSIX-like shells. Settings like `$PATH`, you might have in your `.login` or `.cshrc`, won't be applied.

Maybe you play with `tramp-remote-path` and alike, in order to get better results.